# Why is my code ignoring underscores?

Tags: string, excel, vba, loops

I am writing a very simple vba code that is designed to iterate through the letters/numbers in each cell in row 2 and only keep the numbers in the beginning. Each cell starts with between 4 and 7 numbers, and then will be followed by either a letter (1 or more), a `.` and a number, or an underscore and a letter and a number.

The issue I am having is that my code is only returning the correct values for some of the cells. Only the cells that have a `.` are cleaned correctly. The ones with the underscore delete everything after the `_`, but keep the `_` itself and the cells with letters keep the letters but delete the `.` and anything after it.

This is my code:

```
Sub getIDs()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Dim rowCounter As Integer
rowCounter = 2
Dim original As String
original = ""
Dim newText As String
newText = ""

Do While Len(Cells(rowCounter, 2)) > 0
    Do While counter <= Len(Cells(rowCounter, 2))
        If Not IsNumeric((Mid(Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value, counter, 1))) Or Mid(Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value, counter, 1) = "_" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Loop
    newText = Left(Cells(rowCounter, 2), counter)
    Cells(rowCounter, 2) = newText
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Examples: The original cells contain these four types of info (numbers vary):

```
Input            Desired output    Actual output  Actual output OK?
----------------|-----------------|--------------|-------------------------
12345_v2.jpg     12345             12345_         No, "_" should be removed
293847.psd       293847            293847         OK
82364382.1.tga   82364382          82364382       OK  
172982C.5.tga    172982            172982C        No, "C" should be removed
```

Comment: Please *show* us a few illustrative examples of: input, desired output, and actual output of your current code.

Comment: is it cause you forgot to reset the `counter`?

Comment: I don't believe you. I have run your code, and the periods in 2nd and 3rd make it into the result like the underscores and letters. You don't notice it because you output the result into a cell, and Excel removes the trailing decimal dot for you. Use `counter - 1` in your `Left`. Also replace the inner `While` with a `For`.

Comment: I did forget to reset the counter, and adjusting it to counter-1 fixed the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So I found two problems with your code.  The first that counter, really needs to be counter-1 when you set new text since that is the position of the non-numeric or underscore character.  Copying at the counter point will give you an extra character.

The second issue is that you need to reset the counter variable outside of the inner Do loop, otherwise you will start at the position of the previous last found character.  Try this.

```
Sub getIDs()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Dim rowCounter As Integer
rowCounter = 2
Dim original As String
original = ""
Dim newText As String
newText = ""

Do While Len(Cells(rowCounter, 2)) > 0
    counter = 1
    Do While counter <= Len(Cells(rowCounter, 2))
        If Not IsNumeric((Mid(Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value, counter, 1))) Or Mid(Cells(rowCounter, 2).Value, counter, 1) = "_" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Loop
    newText = Left(Cells(rowCounter, 2), counter - 1)
    Cells(rowCounter, 2) = newText
    rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove dots and underscores.

I have to run; no time to implement removing letters. But this should put you on the right track. I may continue tomorrow.

```
Sub lkjhlkjh()
    Dim s As String
    Dim iUnderscore As Long
    Dim iDot As Long
    Dim iCut As Long
    s = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)
    iUnderscore = InStr(s, "_")
    iDot = InStr(s, ".")
    If iUnderscore = 0 Then
        If iDot = 0 Then
            'Don't cut
        Else
            iCut = iDot
        End If
    Else
        If iDot = 0 Then
            iCut = iUnderscore
        Else
            If iDot > iUnderscore Then
                iCut = iUnderscore
            Else
                iCut = iDot
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If iCut > 0 Then s = Left(s, iCut - 1)
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = s
End Sub
```